# How to run data node block scanner on data node in a cluster from a remote machine

Tags: hdfs

How to run data node block scanner on data node in a cluster from a remote machine.

By default data node executes block scanner in 504 hours. This is the default value of dfs.datanode.scan.period . If I want to run the data node block scanner then  one way is to configure the property of dfs.datanode.scan.period in hdfs-site.xml but is there any other other way. Is it possible to run data node block scanner on data node either through command or pragmatically.

Comment: which version of HDFS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to issue a command from the command-line to trigger the block scanner to run on a Datanode. As you mentioned it your question, the only way to control the frequency of the block scanner process is by changing the value of the 'dfs.datanode.scan.period' setting in your hdfs-site.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. Remove the cursor file.

See https://javagc.leponceau.org/2017/10/hdfs-tricks.html